# eval in R behavior

Tags: r, eval

I am trying to understand eval function behaviour inside a function, so assume this is my setting:

Two global variables x and a are defined

```
x <- 'a'
a <- 'c'
```

Then a function f is defined with three print statements, I am confused with the fact that eval, envir parameter defaults to parent.frame() but however, if I put it deliberately the results are different. Why?

Below is the code with the comments to understand more, Thanks very much for answers the comments to solve this in advance.

```
f <- function(x){
  ## 1st statement, I get it that evaluation should be done in current environment 
  print(eval(quote(x), envir = environment()))
  
  
  ## 2nd statement, This I don't get, as the default is parent.frame(), shouldn't it be 
  ## evaluated in the calling scope of function which is global environment. As per 
  ## documentation parent.frame() is the default then why this result evaluates to current
  ## environment, whereas the last print statement when specifically mentions parent.frame gives a different result entirely.
  ## Note the documentation says: If envir is not specified, then the default is parent.frame() (the environment where the call to eval was made).
  ## So, my understanding of parent.frame is that it is that frame where calls are happening(basically calling environment), Am I mistaken here?
  print(eval(quote(x)))
  
  ## 3rd , This behaviour seems okay as parent.frame is referencing the calling scope which is global
  print(eval(quote(x), envir=parent.frame()))
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> #> f(a)
> #[1] "c"
> #[1] "c"
> #[1] "a"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scoping of supplied arguments and default arguments is different.

Supplied arguments are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the caller, i.e. `f` in your example.  So the envir is set to the `parent.frame` of that call, which is the global environment.

Default arguments are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function where they are defined, `eval` in your example.  In the `eval()` call, the parent frame is the evaluation frame of `f`.

If you think about it a bit, this makes a ton of sense.  As author of `f()`, you should know what variables are visible while evaluating it, so those are the ones used to evaluate argument expressions.  On the other hand, the author of `eval()` has no idea what will be available in its callers, so default arguments have to be evaluated in its own evaluation frame.